# Solve system of linear equation

Tags: matrices

Can anyone help we solve the following:

Find  $X$ so that $F'(X)=0$

s.t.

$F(X)=hX^T-\frac{1}{2}X^T \Lambda_p X$

Where $X$ is a vector with elements $x_i$ and $Λ_p$ is a matrix with diagonal elements $λ_{ii}$ and off-diagonal elements $ρλ_{ij}$.

And the assumptions: 
 $λ_{ii}$ is a constant $λ_0$ for all $i$, and $λ_{ij}=λ_{ji}$ for all $i$ and $j$.
Further, $0≤λ_{ij}$ and for any $i$:

$$∑_jλ_{ij} =1-λ_0$$ 
Now find
 $X$ so that $F'(X)=0$.

I know the result is:
$x_i=h/(λ_0+ρ(1-λ_0))$  for all $i$.

But I don't know how to get there. Can anyone help?

Comment: You seem to have an undisplayable character - note that you can type mathematical symbols between dollars by using LaTeX, so between dollars \rho produces $\rho$, and so on.

Comment: It occurs to me that maybe the character *is* displayable on your computer, so to help you identify it, it's the one between $\sum_j$ and $\lambda_{ij}$.

Comment: Thanks, I hadnt noticed that. There should not be a character there at all. It sould simply read ∑_j λ_ij =1-λ_0

Comment: OK - it's gone now.